# Why did English adopt both 'estrange' and 'strange'?

Tags: etymology, french

I'm not asking about the definitions of **estrange** and **strange**, and I realise that modern usage isn't a strict function of the original meaning of a word. I wish to know why English appropriated both words.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=estrange+&searchmode=none) doesn't explain this. Its mention of  the Modern French « étrange », worsens my confusion, because it insinuates some hidden reason why French only appropriated one Latin word. I read [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/64612?rskey=u3Uht0&result=2&isAdvanced=false) but it's too brusque; so I don't quote it.

Comment: Because it would be strange for English not to.

Comment: There is no central registry or authority about how people talk, so there is no "adoption" ceremony and no record is kept about when who uses which word where and how. So a word can be "adopted" millions of times before it takes. Why it takes in some cases and not in others is as random as any other mutational evolutionary phenomenon.

Comment: There is no answer as to *why*, even though [a decent answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/238780/78616) can tell you *when*, based on extant samples.

Comment: I've never heard of the word 'estrange' before - it must be very uncommon. A better example would be why we have both 'especially' and 'specially'.

Answer (score 2):

English borrowed *estrange* (the adjective) from the French in the 13th century. This was early enough that it lost the initial *'e',* like *strive*, *strait*, *strap, strife, stable* (from *estriver*, *estrait*, *estrop, estrif, estable*, all borrowed mid-14th century or earlier).

The verb *estrange* was borrowed in the late 15th century, after the adjective *strange* had already lost its initial *e*. Words borrowed in the 15th century and later seem to have kept their initial *'e'*, like *establish* (borrowed in the late 14th century) and *estop* (borrowed 15th century).

You can see from my examples that this isn't the only time something like this has happened: *establish* and *stable* come from very similar words in French, but *stable* was borrowed earlier.

Answer (score 1):

While "Strange" is an ADJECTIVE, "Estrange" is a VERB. Both words are required, so both have been adopted (or adapted) into English. Otherwise, some new word(s) would have been required for the verb form.

Consider the word Cactus from latin. It was borrowed together with the plural form cacti, but some folks use cactuses, which is a "new" word formed with English "rules" for plurals.

In the case of "Strange" & "Estrange", both forms are borrowed, rather than borrowing one word and making a new word for the variations.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is why the SAME word (Old French estrange) was borrowed into English twice, with two different forms in English.

Comment: @fdb, I am not sure what you mean.          **(A)** OP is saying "I wish to know why English appropriated both words." and I replied that English requires both forms ADJECTIVE & VERB, otherwise it has to make a new word                     **(B)** The provided reference [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=estrange+&searchmode=none) says that there were 2 **Different** French words "Old French estrange" & "Middle French estrangier" which were borrowed.

Comment: @Prem Sorry, but I meant to say something alike to user 'fdb' 's comment above. Why was the same ROOT, whatever it was (instead of 2 later disparate French words) borrowed into English twice, with two different forms in English? Does your answer explain this?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit , No Problem, you should edit your question for clarity. Unfortunately , I do not  know about the "Why", and currently I do not see any answer (or comment) regarding the "Why". The only other answer (by Peter Shor) gives the timelines when it happened & mentions that is is a common occurrence, but does not answer the "why". Maybe somebody will answer soon.